# Calling printf without a connected monitor

Tags: linux, drivers, c, monitors, printf

I would like to know if when we call `printf` without connecting a monitor (and uninstalling any driver related to the screen), does a driver get called anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing several things.

All Unix processes have special file descriptors called `stdin` (standard in), `stdout` (standard out), and `stderr` (standard error). If you call `printf` (or similar functions), you produce a byte stream on `stdout`.

What the OS does with that byte stream entirely depends on what the `stdout` descriptor is connected to. You can connect it to a file (and then all the OS layers for the file system get called, inclusive "drivers" if the file system is backed by physical hardware). You can connect it to `/dev/null`, then the "driver" for this device is called (which will just ignore it). You can pipe it to another process.

That's unrelated to if you have a monitor connected, or if all "drivers related to the screen" are installed or not.

So please read up a bit on Unix and Linux basics, and terminal emulators, and terminal settings; that will help you understand the many layers that are involved in that.

Comment: so if I understand you answer correctly, the printf will write to the file and not call any driver. Only later a driver may be called if the `stdout` is connected to some kind of device? and if a screen is not connected then no driver will be called?

Comment: No. `printf` will (eventually) do OS calls that tell the OS that the process writes to `stdout`. What happens then depends entirely what `stdout` is connected to. Also, your idea that there is somehow "a driver" involved is extremely naive. During the processing of the output lots of things get called that you could call a "driver" (or not). As I said, please read up a bit on how this all works.